# How to find out when was a photo taken?

Tags: macos, mac, photos, finder, metadata

I am trying to find out when some of the pictures I own have been taken. In Mac OS X, in Finder, I am looking at the photo. There is date created, but it is not correct. I assume it is the date when I copied the photo to Mac. The picture is taken in 2008, and the date is in 2009. I thought digital cameras store date when the picture is taken. There is all kind of metadata for the picture, but not date taken. I have checked for pictures taken by different cameras.

According to [Exchangeable image file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format#Viewing_and_editing_Exif_data) article on Wikipedia, `right click the image > Get Info > More Info` should do it, but it does not. I can not believe that none of the cameras saved date taken.

Am I doing something wrong? How to see when the picture was taken?

I have access to Mac, Windows and Linux machines, if it is easier to see in any of them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it in Preview.

`Tools > Inspector > More Info tab (in the middle)` and then `Exif` of `TIFF` tab.

I am still not convinced the actual time when the image was taken is recorded there, it looks to me that in some cases the time when the image was moved to a computer is there, but that could be camera specific. Good enough for now.

Comment: Some photo importing programs change the date/time in the exif tag to the date the program imported the photo.

Comment: In many cases that time is unreliable because no one thinks to (re)set the time on their camera through things like daylight savings time, battery changes, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I googled to find this link. It is a program called 'exifme' which retrieves the date and time info.

http://otvox.com/exifme.htm